# Show the consistency of an estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, statistical-inference, order-statistics

Let $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,...,Y_n$ be a random sample from the exponential distribution having PDF $f(y;\lambda)= \lambda e^{-y\lambda},$  $y>0.$

A) Show that $\hat\lambda_n = Y_1$ is not consistent for $\lambda$.

B)Show that $\hat\lambda_n =\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y^2_i$  is not consistent for $\lambda$.

The hint in the back of the book has probably confused me but it says to use $P(Y_1 > 2\lambda)$ and I don't see where that is coming from. I was assuming that I was going to use an epsilon-delta proof, or use chebyshev's but now I'm just confused.

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: Intro to Mathematical Statistics by Larsen & Marx

Comment: The trouble is that $E(Y_1)=1/\lambda$, not $\lambda$...

Comment: I don't understand. Could you elaborate? I'm honestly still confused but I feel like @heropop beat the problem to death for me and I didn't want to keep asking question to what seems like an answered problem.

Comment: Could I elaborate *what*? As I already explained, $E(Y_1)=1/\lambda$, not $\lambda$, hence to use $\hat\lambda=Y_1$ to estimate $\lambda$ is absurd. Did you at least check you did not miscopy the exercise or are you happy with asking to "elaborate" an already perfectly clear comment?

Comment: It wasn't perfectly clear to me. So I went ahead and asked, and you elaborated so thank you. I'll ignore the rest.

Comment: Sorry but *what did I elaborate* in my second comment that was not already in the first one? To elaborate = to repeat?

Comment: I didn't automatically see why $E(Y) =\frac{1}{\lambda}$ mattered. In your second comment you mentioned why its absurd to use $\hat\lambda$ as an estimator in that condition, which in my case clarified it. To elaborate = To repeat with more detail.

Comment: Perhaps "$E(Y_1)=1/\lambda$ (ought to have) mattered" because my first comment qualified it as "the trouble"? O well...

Answer (score 1):

A consistent estimator will converge in probability to the parameter it estimates, for increasing sample size.  Clearly our intuition says that $\hat \lambda_n = Y_1$ will not:  the first observation of a sample of size $5$ is no different than the first observation of a sample of size $5000000$.  So, you can see that $\Pr[Y_1 > 2\lambda]$ is a constant function of $n$, which contradicts consistency:  if $\hat \lambda_n$ were consistent, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[|\hat\lambda_n - \lambda| \ge \epsilon] = 0$$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

With the above in mind, I leave part (B) to you to consider further.

---

Okay, so if you want an explicit proof:  Let $\hat \lambda_n = Y_1$. Then for any $\epsilon \in (0,\lambda]$, $$\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[|\hat \lambda_n - \lambda| \ge \epsilon] &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[|Y_1 - \lambda| \ge \epsilon] \\ &\ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[Y_1 \ge \epsilon + \lambda] \\ &\ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[Y_1 \ge 2\lambda] \\ &> 0. \end{align*}$$  Therefore, such an estimator is not consistent.

Comment: I still don't understand what $P(Y_1 >2\lambda)$ has to do with it or how that even came up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you calculate that probability?  Does that probability depend on $n$ in any way?  Then as the limit as $n \to \infty$ of that expression, will the result tend to $0$?  If this choice of $\hat \lambda_n$ were consistent, why would such a probability need to tend to $0$?

Comment: The probability would be $e^{-2\lambda^2}$, and I hear what you're saying but why $P(Y_1>2\lambda)$ and not $3\lambda$ or $4\lambda$. Like I said that information is not given, it is in the back as part of the solution and I don't understand where it is coming from. Am I missing the point completely?

Comment: It's just a particular choice of counterexample.  There isn't any special reason to choose $2\lambda$, but note that the choice $\lambda$ is insufficient.  $2$ is merely the next integer multiple of $\lambda$.  We could have also chosen $1.0001\lambda$.

Comment: Although I do understand what you are saying and the reason why A & B are consistent is now clear to me I still don't know how to fully show it. The example in the book for a different problem with different pdf uses an estimator with $Y_{max}$ and order statistics to show it is equal to 1. I've tried doing the same with $\hat\lambda_n = Y_1 =Y_{min}$ to show that $P(\lambda - \epsilon < Y_{min} < \lambda + \epsilon)$ is an integral that integrates to something that should allow to take a limit to show that it is actually less than 1, but have failed.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood:  $Y_1$ is the **first** observation, not the minimum observation.  That would be denoted $Y_{(1)}$.

Comment: the pdf for $Y_{min}$ that I came up with is $n\lambda e^{-y(\lambda + \lambda(n-1))}$. Am I wrong to think that after integrating this with the bounds above that I should be to show after taking a limit that it is in fact less than 1?

Comment: oh ok thanks. Yeah my book use Y for both regular and ordered and it doesn't always differentiate when it using which but it makes total sense that it otherwise would of used $Y_min$.